# Extract substring as number from string typescript

Tags: typescript

This is the format of the string:

[image]
[image]

I want to extract the Revision number from the name. I tried using Substring() but I need a generic solution that could extract out Revision number from any name in this format.
This is how the name is being set is the backend:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the "Revision" word can be translated? You're left with the parenthesis and the number to recognize the pattern, isn't it a bit too fragile? That being said I've provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with a capturing group like this:

```js
const input = 'Access2 - changed - (Revision 2)';

const regex = /^.*\(\w+\s(\d+)\)$/;

const [, revision] = regex.exec(input);

console.log(revision);
```

Comment: May I please know what does the regex group target?

Comment: the capturing group (unescaped parenthesis) surrounds the decimals that you need to retrieve, the result is an array with the full match, then the capturing group match. It retrieves the revision number when the input string is in the form of `any characters(anyletters 123)` where `123` can be one or more decimals

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const [,revisionNumber] = value.match(/Revision (\d)/)
```

Comment: Won't it throw exception when value is an empty string?

Comment: It will, to prevent that you can add `|| []` at the end of the line, then revisionNumber will simply be undefined